How libraries logs depenencies when then don't directly reference Application Insights?
In Application Insights, I can see dependencies like SQL, Http, etc being logged and associated with http request.
I wonder how are these logs produced, when those libraries does not reference application insights?

The Application Insights SDKs for .NET and .NET Core include a built-in feature called DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule that automatically tracks external calls your app makes, like database queries or API calls. For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core apps, this feature is turned on by default when you set things up as explained in the official docs. It comes as part of the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector NuGet package, which is automatically added if you install the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web or Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore packages. This doc will help you more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies
